# C#, TextBox '&' char changes to amp;

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a TextBox binded to a String Url property.
When the user insert a link with the char '&' it changes to amp;
This cause me lots of problems on other applications
Is there a way to disable this conversion ?

Thanks

Comment: Becuase you are binding it to a Url it is automatically getting UrlEncoded. There is probably no way to unset it BUT you must be able to programatically set it in code (I assume you are using some declarative method for binding it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. amp; is actually the correct way of doing querty/get strings. The reason for is that & is how the browser sees the end of a variable in the URL; & being a variable spliter. Putting in amp; makes sure the browsers know exactly that that isn't the end of the variable. This is a global standard which all browsers are to adhere to.

Here is a good resource on this kind of stuff

http://www.w3.org/